# Validation of Multiple radiobox with different name using javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I have the following code. This is a quiz and i want to validate the quiz form in such a way that user have to attempt all the questions. Without answering all the questions user can not proceed to submission. A alertbox should be displayed if any question is not answered.

My code is as follows

```
<form method="post" action="" name="quizform" id="quizform">

<h4> 1)This is first question</h4>
a) <input type="radio" name="a1" value="1" id="1" /><label for="1">Option 1</label><br />
b) <input type="radio" name="a1" value="2" id="2" /><label for="2">Option 1</label><br />
c) <input type="radio" name="a1" value="3" id="3" /><label for="3">Option 1</label><br />
d) <input type="radio" name="a1" value="4" id="4" /><label for="4">Option 1</label><br />

<h4> 2)This is first question</h4>
a) <input type="radio" name="a2" value="1" id="5" /><label for="5">Option 1</label><br />
b) <input type="radio" name="a2" value="2" id="6" /><label for="6">Option 1</label><br />
c) <input type="radio" name="a2" value="3" id="7" /><label for="7">Option 1</label><br />
d) <input type="radio" name="a2" value="4" id="8" /><label for="8">Option 1</label><br />

<h4> 3)This is first question</h4>
a) <input type="radio" name="a3" value="1" id="9" /><label for="9">Option 1</label><br />
b) <input type="radio" name="a3" value="2" id="10" /><label for="10">Option 1</label><br />
c) <input type="radio" name="a3" value="3" id="11" /><label for="11">Option 1</label><br />
d) <input type="radio" name="a3" value="4" id="12" /><label for="12">Option 1</label><br />

<h4> 4)This is first question</h4>
a) <input type="radio" name="a4" value="1" id="13" /><label for="13">Option 1</label><br />
b) <input type="radio" name="a4" value="2" id="14" /><label for="14">Option 1</label><br />
c) <input type="radio" name="a4" value="3" id="15" /><label for="15">Option 1</label><br />
d) <input type="radio" name="a4" value="4" id="16" /><label for="16">Option 1</label><br />
<input type="submit" onclick="formButtonFever('quizform','submit')" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    hope this will help you

    <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function formButtonFever(form){
    ErrorText= "";
    if ( ( form.a1[0].checked == false ) && ( form.a1[1].checked == false ) && (  
    form.a1[2].checked == false )&& ( form.a1[3].checked == false )) 
    {
    alert ( "Please answer for 1st question" ); 
    return false;
    }

    if ( ( form.a2[0].checked == false ) && ( form.a2[1].checked == false ) && (     
    form.a2[2].checked == false )&& ( form.a2[3].checked == false )) 
     {
     alert ( "Please answer for 2nd question" ); 
     return false;
     }

     if ( ( form.a3[0].checked == false ) && ( form.a3[1].checked == false ) && (  
     form.a3[2].checked == false )&& ( form.a3[3].checked == false )) 
     {
      alert ( "Please answer for 3rd question" ); 
     return false;
       }


      if ( ( form.a4[0].checked == false ) && ( form.a4[1].checked == false ) && ( 
      form.a4[2].checked == false )&& ( form.a4[3].checked == false )) 
      {
      alert ( "Please answer for 4th question" ); 
      return false;
      }




      if (ErrorText= "") { form.submit() }
       }
       </script>



       <form method="post" action="" name="quizform" id="quizform">

                    //your code

       <input type="submit" onclick="return formButtonFever(this.form)" />
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: thank you Ezhil. It worked. But but it is creating a problem. If any question is left unanswered  It is clearing all the fields and user have to check all options again.

Comment: replace <input type="submit" onclick="formButtonFever(this.form)" /> to  <input type="submit" onclick=" return formButtonFever(this.form)" />

Comment: thanks. Can you please suggest one more thing. I want to show the corresponding <h4> in alert box. Is there any way to do so. I will be comfortable to use hidden input containing the same content as h4 if it may make solution esay.

Comment: exactly whats is your requirement

Comment: Finally i solved it... A great thanks to u ezhil.. :)

Comment: The listener should be on the form's submit handler, not the submit button. Every button must be hard coded, there are other solutions here that don't require that, the value of `ErrorText` is never modified, submitting the form by calling its submit method is not necessary, all that is required is to not return `false`. The language attribute for script elements was deprecated 15 years ago and is removed from HTML5. The value provided is not valid for the very rare occasions a long time ago when it made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I found this example that I think answers your question

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateRadio( obj,correct ){
    var result = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
        if(obj[i].checked==true && obj[i].value==correct){
            result = 1;
        }
    }
    if(!result && obj.value == correct){
        result = 1;
    }
    return result
}

function validateSubmit( obj ){
    var err = '';
    if( !validateRadio( obj.a,3 ) ){ err+='\nFirst radio is wrong'; }
    if( !validateRadio( obj.b,2 ) ){ err+='\nSecond radio is wrong'; }
    if( err.length ){ 
        alert('Problem:'+err); 
        return false; 
    }
    else{ 
        alert('Good Job -- Submitting'); 
        return true; 
    }
}
</script>
<form onsubmit="return validateSubmit(this);" action="#">


Choose "3"
<input type="radio" name="a" value="1" onchange="if(!validateRadio(this,3)) alert('Incorrect');"> 1
<input type="radio" name="a" value="2" onchange="if(!validateRadio(this,3)) alert('Incorrect');"> 2
<input type="radio" name="a" value="3" onchange="if(!validateRadio(this,3)) alert('Incorrect');"> 3
<input type="radio" name="a" value="4" onchange="if(!validateRadio(this,3)) alert('Incorrect');"> 4

<p>Choose "2"
<input type="radio" name="b" value="1"> 1
<input type="radio" name="b" value="2"> 2
<input type="radio" name="b" value="3"> 3
<input type="radio" name="b" value="4"> 4

</p><p><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</p></form>
```

Reference : http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript/javascript-example-how-to-validate-radio-buttons.htm

Comment: Dear vova thanks for your answer, but it is not what i am looking for. User have to select one radio button from every group. In other words we can say that user has to answer every question.

Comment: I have a logic to solve my problem but don't know how to implement in javascript. The logis is that we can count the checked number of radio buttons and if it is less than total number of questions in the quiz that means any question is left blank

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to iterate over the form's *elements* collection and check that each radio button group has at least one checked:

```
function checkRadios(form) {

  // All elements in the form
  var elements = form.elements,
      visited = {},
      name,
      node,
      result = true;

  // Loop over elements looking for raido button groups
  for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    node = elements[i];
    name = node.name;

    // Store whether one radio in the group is checked
    if (node.type == 'radio') {
      visited[name] = node.checked || !!visited[name];
    }
  }

  // Deal with unchecked radios
  for (name in visited) {
    if (visited.hasOwnProperty(name) && !visited[name]) {
      console.log(name + ' has not been checked');
      result = false;
    }
  }

  // Return false if one group not checked
  return result;
}
```

You should include a reset button in the form too:

```
<form onsubmit="return checkRadios(this);">
Choose "3"
<input type="radio" name="a" value="1"> 1
<input type="radio" name="a" value="2"> 2
<input type="radio" name="a" value="3"> 3
<input type="radio" name="a" value="4"> 4
<br>
Choose "2"
<input type="radio" name="b" value="1"> 1
<input type="radio" name="b" value="2"> 2
<input type="radio" name="b" value="3"> 3
<input type="radio" name="b" value="4"> 4
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><input type="reset">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer. At first you should provide `class` for each `radio button`, `name` **a1** have `class` **a1**, `name` **a2** have `class` **a2** and so on...Then

try like this..

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function()
    { var flag=0;
        var a1 = $('.a1').is(':checked');
        var a2 = $('.a2').is(':checked');
        var a3 = $('.a3').is(':checked');
        var a4 = $('.a4').is(':checked');
        if(a1 ==false||a2==false||a3==false||a4==false)
        {
            flag =1;
        }
        if(flag==1)
        {
            alert("plaese answer all questions!");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's far better to put a submit listener on the form, not the submit button (because forms can be submitted without clicking the submit button). A class isn't needed to use a selector, `'input[type=radio]'` will get all the radio buttons and `'input[type=radio]:checked'` will get just the checked ones.